# Passing wildcard to Oracle from SQL Server Openquery

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-11g, linked-server

I want to pass a wildcard to Oracle from MS SQL Server like this...

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MY_LINKED_ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT * FROM MY_ORACLE_TABLE')
```

I'm trying to get everything from table MY_ORACLE_TABLE.

I get the following output...

```
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "MY_LINKED_ORACLE_SERVER" returned message "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-06512: at "OPS$MY_LINKED_ORACLE_SERVER.PERS_GET_SERVICE_LENGTH", line 43
ORA-06512: at "OPS$MY_LINKED_ORACLE_SERVER.PERS_GET_SERVICE_LENGTH", line 68
ORA-06512: at "OPS$MY_LINKED_ORACLE_SERVER.PRBI_GET_LENGTH_OF_SERVICE", line 9".
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "MY_LINKED_ORACLE_SERVER" returned message "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-06512: at "OPS$MY_LINKED_ORACLE_SERVER.PERS_GET_SERVICE_LENGTH", line 43
ORA-06512: at "OPS$MY_LINKED_ORACLE_SERVER.PERS_GET_SERVICE_LENGTH", line 68
ORA-06512: at "OPS$MY_LINKED_ORACLE_SERVER.PRBI_GET_LENGTH_OF_SERVICE", line 9".
Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot execute the query "SELECT * FROM MY_ORACLE_TABLE" against OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "MY_LINKED_ORACLE_SERVER".
```

Looks like something isn't formatted to the liking of SQL Server but as I don't know what column names exist at the remote Oracle server (and I've no way to find out) is this possible to fix?

Comment: Did you mean `SELECT * ...`? The `%` wildcard is used for string matching by the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: That's exactly my question... what syntax is used to Select * (all) in this scenario?  However,  I also tried using * and I get the same error.  Also, I thought I read somewhere that Oracle uses % where SQL Server uses *.

Comment: mustaccio - I edited my question to give a better view of the problem

Comment: The Oracle error message does not match they query you are showing; it makes no sense to post bogus code and expect people to troubleshoot something they don't see.

Comment: It's not a message from Oracle - its a message from SQL Server after running the SQL Statement.  It does make sense in so far as when I run the code I get the above message.  I agree I'm asking for assistance to troubleshoot something you can't see, but neither can I and that is exactly why I'm asking - my question remains... How do I get all data (all columns and all rows) from a table on a linked Oracle server when I know the table name but I don't know the column names?  Mustaccio... Pls. remove the down vote as this question is genuine and I can't explain it any differently.

Comment: "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string" _is_ an Oracle error and it has nothing to do with column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error arises from a failing function on the Oracle side.  "SELECT * FROM MY_ORACLE_TABLE" is the correct syntax however one of the columns is calculated as the 'table' is actually a view with a computed column and the underlying data is poorly formatted for the function e.g. a numeric function called on a text value.